# Ubuntu failed to boot due to acpi / bios error after updating bios through windows update

Tags: ubuntu, bios, acpi

Failed to boot to ubuntu, Error occurred during file checking process.

After 13.4 % completion it moves me to emergency mode.

[image: This is what comes after failure of file check]

Problem occurred after updating bios through windows

laptop -> Asus X512F vivobook

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know please help me as i had to submit assignment today, which is on ubuntu

Comment: If your assignment is all you care about at the moment, you could boot from an Ubuntu installation media and access files on your computer from it.

Comment: but i read somewhere that accessing ubuntu files can be dangerous from windows

Comment: I think what @RomanRiabenko is saying here is to boot from a live ubuntu usb (just like you would to install ubuntu), but do not install it. You will have the UI of the live usb and the terminal to use - then mount the partition you have ubuntu installed on and you will be able to navigate through your files that way

Comment: If you still have Windows installed and operable you could install ext2fsd in **readonly** (I do not trust its write mode) mode and access your Linux files.